# Convert decimal to any base (using switch statement for base>=10)

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, converters

I'm trying to use the switch statement in order to convert a decimal number
into a base (which is greater than 9) and save the remainder into an array,
however, I'm not getting the desired result, as it looks like I'm messing up the switch statement.
Example : 200(10) = 678(16) <- should be C8.
Could you advise?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x,y,yCopy,q,r,cnt=0;
        cout << "Select a base for your number from 2 to 16 : ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Enter a decimal number in order to transform it to the selected base : " << endl;
        cin >> y;
            yCopy=y;

    do{
        yCopy=yCopy/x;
        cnt++;
    }while(yCopy!=0);
        yCopy=y;

        int result[cnt];

    if(x>1 && x<10){
        for(int i=cnt-1; i>=0;--i){
            r=yCopy%x;
            result[i]=r;
            yCopy=yCopy/x;
        }

        cout << y << "(10) = ";
        for(int i=0;i<cnt;++i){
            cout << result[i];
        }
        cout << "(" << x <<  ")" << endl;
    }

    if(x>9 && x<17){
        for(int i=cnt-1; i>=0;--i){
            r=yCopy%x;
            switch(r){
            case 10 : r='A'; break;
            case 11 : r='B'; break;
            case 12 : r='C'; break;
            case 13 : r='D'; break;
            case 14 : r='E'; break;
            case 15 : r='F';
            }
            result[i]=r;
            yCopy=yCopy/x;
        }

        cout << y << "(10) = ";
        for(int i=0;i<cnt;++i){
            cout << result[i];
        }
        cout << "(" << x << ")" << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `x` is a really bad name for a variable that represents the base. Why not call it `base` and reduce the cognitive load required by readers of your code? `y` has a similar issue.

Comment: `q` is a pretty bad variable name too.  You wouldn't even notice if the variable never got used.

Comment: also unrelated, I think every case needs a break statement, including "case: 15". Also agreed that you should vastly improve your naming conventions, try using camelcase or underscores, then use 1-3 words to describe that variable

Comment: Hint: The ASCII code for the character `C` is 67.

Comment: `int` means ["integer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).  Your program only ever prints integer variables.  You should not expect any integer to be `C`.

Comment: You should use a std::vector<char> to hold your results.

Comment: You could use `std::string` to contain your results, because `A6` is more of a string than two integers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification , everyone!
As some of you mentioned, I'm using the data types incorrectly here.
I've changed the array to char (for bases>=10),
added a couple more cases for nums 0-9 and that worked.
Much appreciated!

```
if(base>9 && base<17){
        char remainder;
        char arr[cnt];
        for(int i=cnt-1; i>=0;--i){
            remainder=yCopy%base;
            switch(remainder){
            case 0 : remainder='0'; break;
            case 1 : remainder='1'; break;
            case 2 : remainder='2'; break;
            case 3 : remainder='3'; break;
            case 4 : remainder='4'; break;
            case 5 : remainder='5'; break;
            case 6 : remainder='6'; break;
            case 7 : remainder='7'; break;
            case 8 : remainder='8'; break;
            case 9 : remainder='9'; break;
            case 10 : remainder='A'; break;
            case 11 : remainder='B'; break;
            case 12 : remainder='C'; break;
            case 13 : remainder='D'; break;
            case 14 : remainder='E'; break;
            case 15 : remainder='F';
            }
            arr[i]=remainder;
            yCopy=yCopy/base;
        }

        cout << y << "(10) = ";
        for(int i=0;i<cnt;++i){
            cout << arr[i];
        }
        cout << "(" << base <<  ")" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: danger here: `char arr[cnt];` Variable Length Arrays are a non-Standard C++ extension.